# stored procedure concatenate two parameters in where clause

Tags: sql

I've got an annoying problem, where I pass two parameters into a stored procedure and join them together for use within the WHERE clause of my statement. The first parameter is used in an equals expression, whereas the second is to form an AND clause.

The below extract of the stored proc, shows what I am attempting to do.

```
Declare @CombinedWhereClause varchar(500), @Sender varchar(10), @AndClause char(200)

Set @Sender = 'Wayne';
Set @AndClause = ' AND Convert(varchar(8), MessageDate, 112) < DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())';
Set @CombinedWhereClause = @Sender + @AndClause;

SELECT Messages.Id, Messages.IdExternal, Messages.MessageReference, 
FROM Messages
WHERE Messages.Sender =@CombinedWhereClause
```

If I replace the @CombinedWhereClause with @Sender only then I get back the expected records. If I change the where clause to be:

```
WHERE Message.MessageDate Convert(varchar(8), MessageDate,112) < DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())
```

then I get all records which are 10 days old. However, when combined I get no results.

Comment: Please tag the dbms. (That's product specific code.)

Comment: Which RDBMS (vendor  and version)? Do you really expect, that the db engine could know, that the string you are comparing against is not a string but a where clause extension? This is possible only with dynamic SQL...

Comment: I assume sql server because of the `getdate()` and `convert()` syntax. Anyway, I don't know of rdbms that can combine regular sql and dynamic sql.

Comment: Injection attack alert

Comment: Wayne, @Jodrell is rigth: Just imagine via user input there might come in a sender of `'hahaha!'; DROP TABLE User; --`; This might lead to really serious injection attacks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your statement are several flaws:

- The comma behind the MessageReference
- You try to have `WHERE Messages.sender=Wayne` but you need quotes `...='Wayne'`
- You think the db engine is somehow magic :-)
- This is - for sure! - not the approach one should chose...

Try this dynamic approach (SQL Server syntax)

```
Declare @CombinedWhereClause varchar(500), @Sender varchar(10), @AndClause char(200)

Set @Sender = '''Wayne'''; --you need to wrap the word in quotes!
Set @AndClause = ' AND Convert(varchar(8), MessageDate, 112) < DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())';
Set @CombinedWhereClause = @Sender + @AndClause;

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT Messages.Id, Messages.IdExternal, Messages.MessageReference 
 FROM Messages
 WHERE Messages.Sender =' + @CombinedWhereClause;

--check the command
SELECT @cmd;

--if the command is OK you might execute it
--EXEC(@cmd);
```

Comment: Thanks Shnugo. just need to wrap this all up into a CTE function now.

Comment: @WayneAtherton, What do you really want? This is dynamic SQL, you cannot just *wrap this all up into a CTE* ... There might be one solution: Create a physical (temp-)table and let the dynamic SQL be an `INSERT` statement to this table. You can then use the tables content in a "normal" query...

Comment: Good call. Thanks for the advice